# C# Calculations With Decimal Places

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with basic multiplication and division in C#.

It returns 0 for ((150 / 336) * 460) but the answer should be 205.357142857.

I presume this is because (150/336) is a fractional number, and C# rounds this down to 0.

How do I correctly calculate this taking into consideration all decimal places?

Comment: Try `((150.0 / 336) * 460)` so that it does the calculation with floating-point numbers instead of integers.

Comment: (150/336)  is not a negative number.

Comment: How is 150/336 a negative number? Do you mean it's not a whole number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is because 150/336 is an integer division which always truncates the decimal part since the result will also be an `int`.

So one of both must be a decimal number:

```
double d = 150d / 336;
```

See: [7.7.2 Division operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
>   the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
>   absolute value of the quotient of the two operands. The result is zero
>   or positive when the two operands have the same sign and zero or
>   negative when the two operands have opposite signs.

Answer (score 5):

```
((150 / 336) * 460)
```

Those numbers are integers, they have no decimal places.  Since `150 / 336` evaluates to `0` in integer math, multiplying it by anything will also result in `0`.

You need to explicitly make each number a double.  Something like this:

```
((150d / 336d) * 460d)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are doing integer arithmetic not floating/double.  To specify a floating point double constant use the 'd' suffix.

```
double d = (150d / 336d) * 460d;
```

Answer (score 2):

150/336 gives you an int as result, thus 0. you need to the division so it you'll have a double as result

```
(((double)150 / 336) * 460)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using variables then you should write it down like this:

```
double d = ((double)firstNumber/ secondNumber) * thirdNumber;
```

For more information: https://www.dotnetperls.com/divide